# What set's the nShowCmd parameter of WinMain?

Tags: c++, windows, winmain

This seems a little strange that i can't find anything about it, but what actually sets the nShowCmd parameter of WinMain? I know what it does, and i know i can set it for windows I create, but when my program starts execution in WinMain, how is the nShowCmd value being set? What actually sets it?

Comment: btw, i've already read through http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In most cases - it does explorer:
[image]

Comment: In general, whatever executed the program. Also see the [`start` command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491005.aspx)...